# Clip element to right when changing screen size

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this element that is on my login screen that I would like when the screen changes size, it holds position. Only today I test on different screen sizes, it moves. How can I make him get stuck in this position?

My code:

```
export const ContainerLogin = styled(Grid).attrs({
  item: true,
})`


  background-color: var(--white-100);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 1242px;
  width: 520px;
  height: 528px;
  top: 226px;
  
  border-radius: 4px;


 
  
`;
```

Update:
Code:

```
  return (
    <ContainerMain >

      <ContainerImagem >
        <img src={backgroundFull} style={{ position: 'fixed', minWidth: '100%', minHeight: '100%', backgroundSize: 'cover', backgroundPosition: 'center', bottom: 0, left: 0, top: 0, right: 0 }} />
      </ContainerImagem>

      <ContainerLogin>
        <motion.div


        >
          {children}
        </motion.div>
      </ContainerLogin>
    </ContainerMain>
  );
};
```

Style:

```
export const ContainerMain = styled(Grid).attrs({
  container: true,
})`

 
  align-items: center;  
  overflow: hidden; 

 
  

 
`;

export const ContainerImagem = styled(Grid).attrs({
  item: true,
})`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;


  

  



 
 
`;

export const ContainerLogin = styled(Grid).attrs({
  item: true,
})`
 /*  position: fixed; */
 
  background-color: var(--white-100);
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  width: 520px;
  height: 528px;
  top: 226px;
  border-radius: 4px;
 /*  z-index: 2;
  left: 1242px;
  width: 520px;
  height: 528px;
  top: 226px;
  border-radius: 4px; */


 
  
`;
```

Imagem result:
[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o9Zk.png)

My screen in this image is zoomed to 80%

Comment: dont use `left:1242px` use `right:0` instead so it will always be on the right side

Comment: @UmairFarooq the problem is that I need this component to have this amount of pixels on the left, because if I remove it, it loses the alignment I would like.

Comment: how would you place the element 1242px from the left if the screen size is lets say only 600px?

Comment: @UmairFarooq I'm afraid I wouldn't be able to answer your question because I don't understand the concepts well yet. but basically, the login screen layout, is an image, which on the right side of it, has a white box with these proportions with 3 input fields and a button. If I take that amount of pixels from the left, the elements all go to the left of the screen and don't stay in a fixed position, either.

Comment: exactly dont position it with left instead use right.which makes more sense.i  willl show you an examplle

Comment: @UmairFarooq right! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

if you go into full page view and resize the window.it will always be on the right side of the window

```css
img {
  width: 60vw;
}

.rightelem {
  background-color: cyan;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  width: 220px;
  height: 228px;
  top: 126px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1664736607930-288b58f7e720?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=764&q=80">
</div>
<div class="rightelem">
  i am on the right side</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! Now, a question.. when I change the size, it moves. But for example, the image of the mountains remains in the same place, how do I get it fixed?

Comment: no it doesn't change. you are change the size from the right. meaning you are grabbing the screen from the right side that's why its moving if you change it from the left the image will change instead

Comment: but there is no way to make it appear as if it were moving, because when I applied it here, and I reduce the screen size, the component leaves the white background and disappears

Comment: can you show me what you added & the results.take a screenshot of both.

Comment: sure. I will edit the question with the images

Comment: I added the image and code

Comment: you are using `position: fixed;` now?  fixed is commenly used for navbars at the top to fixed it when you scroll.fixed on right or left elements will make it stay and go outside the bounds

Comment: No, in this element I commented out the fixed position. I am using position fixed on my background image

Comment: https://imgur.com/p5oFk1L

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that it was like this. I did the way that you did it but my image continues to go outside of the image. Maybe is because my image already has a white box that I'm putting the white box inside of it?